# Unrecognized selector sent to instance from modal view controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am displaying a modal view controller from an NSObject.

I call `presentModalViewController:animated` on `self.sender` which is another view controller. The view controller displays fine, but when I push a button in the view, I get the following error:

> -[__NSCFType buttonCancelPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

This is how I display the modal view controller from my NSObject:

```
FBComposeViewController *composeViewController = [[FBComposeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FBComposeViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.sender presentModalViewController:composeViewController animated:YES];
```

The button is hooked up to a selector in `FBComposeViewController` using Interface Builder.

Does anyone have an idea why I might be getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the binding in FBComposeViewController.xib. What is the target-action  for the cancel button set to?

Comment: It's set to `buttonCancelPressed:` in `Compose View Controller`.

Comment: Of course, there it was! The `File's Owner` was set to be of class `UIViewController`. I changed that to `FBComposeViewController` and linked my buttons to the `File's Owner`. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `self.sender`? Assuming `sender` is a `UIButton` object.

Assuming, this line of code is written in a Controller Class, use:

```
[self presentModalViewController:composeViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: `sender` is not a `UIButton` in this case. It's another view controller. I need to call `presentModalViewController:animated:` on this, as `self` is an `NSObject`. Admitted, `sender` might be an inappropriate for this.